# Why declare self static instance of a class

Tags: java, android

I sometimes see that people create self instance for example:

```
public class Example extends Service
{
    private static Example mInstance = null;


     public void onStart( Intent aIntent, int aStartId )
    {

        mInstance = this;
        .
        .
        .
   }
}
```

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Impossible to tell with the small amount of code you posted. It could be a singleton class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the Singleton design pattern.  Singletons are used when there is going to be a single instance of an object performing operations on non-static data.

See [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).

Comment: This is **not** the singleton pattern. Neither does it restrict object creation by using a non-public constructor, nor does it create one when it's needed the first time.

Comment: Well, it *might* be.  The OP has snipped out a lot of code.  If this isn't a singleton, it is a class with serious problems.

Comment: This exact code is not a full Singleton design, no.  However, given that the instance variable is private and static, a Singleton would make the most sense for the code given.  If the program just wants to use the instance in the code, it could use the *this* keyword.

Comment: Actually, this is almost certainly **not** part of the singleton pattern, since `mInstance` is not being set in the constructor. Besides, an Android `Service` object cannot be implemented as a singleton; the framework needs to be able to access the default constructor for the `Service` class.

Comment: Right, I agree, but OP was asking a general question about private static instance variables.  In general, private static instance variables are either the singleton pattern or bad practice.  In the specific case of the posted code, it's probably just bad practice, as the instance can be referenced using Example.this

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what other answers put about Singleton pattern, self instances may be used as constants. That's the case of the Color class, that defines an instance for each of the common colours.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Answer (score 1):

An Android `Service` (sub)class cannot be a singleton since the framework requires access to a default constructor for the class. The only reason I can think of for keeping a static reference to the (last) instance for which `onStart` was called is to simplify some internal code that may happen to reside in static methods.

Considering that `onStart` was deprecated a long time ago (as of API level 5), this is most likely an example of bad coding style from early days of Android.

Comment: Yeah that would also be my guess. Somewhere in this Service, there is/are static method(s), so to be able to access the Service instance, it should be made static. Really ugly and it doesn't make any sense in a case of managed Android components.

Answer (score 0):

In a thread-unsafe singleton pattern implementation, you would have a private constructor, and a `public static getInstance` method initializing that instance if necessary and returning it.

Here's an example. Note that it is advised to leverage the commodity of a single-element enum instead of the code below, to achieve a "true" singleton.

```
public class MyThreadUnsafeSingleton {
    private static MyThreadUnsafeSingleton instance;
    private MyThreadUnsafeSingleton() {
        //TODO some ctor logic
    }
    public static MyThreadUnsafeSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyThreadUnsafeSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Final note, there is a variation of the above pattern that is thread-safe across a single classloader through the usage of a nested "holder" class, but that's quite out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

So that other classes can get an instance and call instance methods on the object.  Its frequently used with the Singleton pattern.  And for Services and Activities in Android it's a very bad idea-  it keeps a reference to the Activity/Service around after it ends, which will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a private default constructor, it's probably a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

If it doesn't, it's something weird.

This sort of layout forces all object instances of this class to share data, regardless of when they are instantiated.  The object instance on which OnStart is called will become the underlying data source for any references to this class, regardless of when they were declared or instantiated (before or after OnStart), and regardless of what thread they were created on.

Of course it is always possible there are members of the class that don't bother with mInstance.Member and use this.Member instead.  That sort of mixing and matching would probably end up being disastrous.

It's hard to imagine the specific use for this but my guess is that the class is an abstraction of some stateful resource that is global with respect to the process, e.g. a form/window or a web service client that caches its credentials.  Could be anything though.

If this code was written around 2003-2005 (early c# days) I'd guess that it is a sloppy implementation of a Singleton-- it was sort of in vogue back then as design patterns were becoming a thing and Singleton was the example in all the textbooks.  Turns out it's a horrible pattern for dependency injection and mocking, so these days this pattern doesn't get used as much.

Comment: _"The instances are sync'd when the OnStart method is called"_ -- there's no evidence that any syncing is going on here.

Comment: True, it's not really a "sync."  The mInstance object pointer is simply updated in one place, but shared by all.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This paradigm is often used for objects that are heavy or slow to construct and only one is needed.

```
public class Server {
    private static Server server = null;

    // Stop them making their own.
    private Server () {
        // Heavyweight stuff.
    }

    public static Server getServer () {
        if ( server == null ) {
            // Heavy constructor.
            server = new Server();
        }
        return server;
    }
}
```

In a multi-thread environment it is usually combined with the [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).